How to import a folder into postman?
Shows an error "No supported files found for import."
I was trying to import my django folder into postman to test api's. Firstly I tried to do it in the postman app and then i installed postman extension from the vs code, the result was same.

What file types are you trying to import? What's in the folder?

Postman does not accept django folder into import, it takes postman APIs, that could be in the form of JSONs, which have API link, body, headers and all the information related to an API, so you can, import an API type, but not django folder, you can however, manually add request to postman to check you APIs

Postman only support JSON files for imports. You have to define a Postman Collection structure inside a JSON file and then import it.
{
"info": {
  "name": "Example API Collection",
  "description": "This is an example Postman collection.",
  "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
},
"item": [
  {
    "name": "User Operations",
    "description": "Operations related to user management",
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "Get All Users",
        "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "header": [],
          "url": {
            "raw": "https://api.example.com/users",
            "protocol": "https",
            "host": [
              "api",
              "example",
              "com"
            ],
            "path": [
              "users"
            ]
          }
        },
        "response": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Create User",
        "request": {
          "method": "POST",
          "header": [
            {
              "key": "Content-Type",
              "value": "application/json"
            }
          ],
          "body": {
            "mode": "raw",
            "raw": "{\"name\": \"John Doe\", \"email\": \"johndoe@email.com\"}"
          },
          "url": {
            "raw": "https://api.example.com/users",
            "protocol": "https",
            "host": [
              "api",
              "example",
              "com"
            ],
            "path": [
              "users"
            ]
          }
        },
        "response": []
      }
    ]
  }
]

}
If you are confused then create a collection yourself manually and then just export it. You can see how everything is structured.

Postman has the ability to import other file types as imports too, it's not limited to JSON files but these need to be one that's supported in the platform https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/importing-an-api/#supported-api-definitions-formats
